# Задача Яндекс Практикума, class, this. Помогите разобраться

Tags: javascript

```js
class Transport {
  constructor(type, price, vendor, model) {
    this.type = type;
    this.price = price;
    this.vendor = vendor;
    this.model = model;
  }

  getInfo() {
    return `${this.vendor}, ${this.model}`;
  }

  getPrice() {
    return this.price.toLocaleString('ru-RU') + ' ₽';
  }
}

class Car extends Transport {
  constructor(vendor, model, doorsCount, price) {
    super('car', price, vendor, model);
    this.doorsCount = doorsCount;
  }

  getDoorsCount() {
    return `Кол-во дверей: ${this.doorsCount}`;
  }
}

class Bike extends Transport {
  constructor(vendor, model, maxSpeed, price) {
    super('bike', price, vendor, model);
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  }

  getMaxSpeed() {
    return `Макс. скорость: ${this.maxSpeed} км/ч`;
  }
}
```

"Вы устроились разработчиком в автомобильную компанию. Первое задание — починить код, который отвечает за отображение информации о транспорте и цене. Поправьте классы так, чтобы ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'vendor' of undefined больше не отображалась. Вносите изменения только в файл task.js."

Данную задачу я уже сутки пытаюсь решить, как я заметил при обработке проверки запускается другой скрипт и он начинает вызывать функции из классов передавая туда значения. Когда он создаёт new Car и делает вызов getDoorsCount, все параметры пролетают нормально.
А вот при вызове родительского getInfo, все переменные становятся undefind, я прочитал всё что только мог и не могу понять в чём конкретно проблема, почему переменные не передаются при вызове родительской функции.

Модулятор яндекса даёт подсказку что нужно привязать контекст у getinfo и использовать ключевое слово this. Но что-то это не даёт ясности.

Проверка запускает такой код

```js
const catalog = document.querySelector('.page__catalog');

const tpl = (img, title, info, price) => {
  return `
        <img src="${img}" alt="" class="card__image" />
        <div class="card__description">
          <h2 class="card__title">${title}</h2>
          <p class="card__info">
            ${info}
          </p>
          <p class="card__price">${price}</p>
        </div>
  `;
};

for (const item of data) {
  const entityContainer = document.createElement('article');
  entityContainer.classList.add('card', 'catalog__item');
  if (item.type === 'car') {
    const { getDoorsCount, getInfo, getPrice } = new Car(
      item.vendor,
      item.model,
      item.doorsCount,
      item.price
    );
    entityContainer.innerHTML = tpl(item.img, getInfo(), getDoorsCount(), getPrice());
  } else {
    const { getMaxSpeed, getInfo, getPrice } = new Bike(
      item.vendor,
      item.model,
      item.maxSpeed,
      item.price
    );
    entityContainer.innerHTML = tpl(item.img, getInfo(), getMaxSpeed(), getPrice());
  }
  catalog.appendChild(entityContainer);
}
```

Comment: Где тут undefined? не вижу

Comment: это плохая проверка, не надо так делать, надо написать другой проверочный код :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

написано же привяжи контекст в конструкторе car пропиши this.getInfo= this.getInfo.bind(this)

Comment: Да, спасибо! Так же сделал привязку контекста для всех методов и всё заработало, благодарю)

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код:

```
class Transport {
  constructor(type, price, vendor, model) {
    
    this.type = type;
    this.price = price;
    this.vendor = vendor;
    this.model = model;
  }

  getInfo() {
    return `${this.vendor}, ${this.model}`;
  }

  getPrice() {
    return this.price.toLocaleString('ru-RU') + ' ₽';
  }
}

class Car extends Transport {
  constructor(vendor, model, doorsCount, price) {
    super('car', price, vendor, model);
    this.doorsCount = doorsCount;
  }

  getInfo = this.getInfo.bind(this);
  getPrice = this.getPrice.bind(this);
  getDoorsCount = this.getDoorsCount.bind(this);
  
  getDoorsCount() {
    return `Кол-во дверей: ${this.doorsCount}`;
  }
}

class Bike extends Transport {
  constructor(vendor, model, maxSpeed, price) {
    super('bike', price, vendor, model);
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  }

  getInfo = this.getInfo.bind(this);
  getPrice = this.getPrice.bind(this);
  getMaxSpeed = this.getMaxSpeed.bind(this);

 
  getMaxSpeed() {
    return `Макс. скорость: ${this.maxSpeed} км/ч`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Так же можно сделать стрелочные функции

```
class Transport {
  constructor(type, price, vendor, model) {
    this.type = type;
    this.price = price;
    this.vendor = vendor;
    this.model = model;
  }

  getInfo = ()  => {
    return `${this.vendor}, ${this.model}`;
  }

  getPrice = () => {
    return this.price.toLocaleString('ru-RU') + ' ₽';
  }
}

class Car extends Transport {
  constructor(vendor, model, doorsCount, price) {
    super('car', price, vendor, model);
    this.doorsCount = doorsCount;
  }

  getDoorsCount = () => {
    return `Кол-во дверей: ${this.doorsCount}`;
  }
}

class Bike extends Transport {
  constructor(vendor, model, maxSpeed, price) {
    super('bike', price, vendor, model);
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  }

  getMaxSpeed = () => {
    return `Макс. скорость: ${this.maxSpeed} км/ч`;
  }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).